# Change the Background color of the top navigation for our site and add a button

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have a modern communication site inside our SharePoint Online tenant, and we want to do the following modification to our top navigation area:-

1. Change the background color to be dark blue
2. Add a button on the top-right corner >> and when users click on this an external link will open.

Here is what we need to build:-

[image]

So can anyone advice how we can achieve the above 2 points?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An SPFx application customiser is limited to the top and bottom part of a page and does not change the out-of-the-box SharePoint navigation bar. Therefore, it wouldn't be possible to add the button.

[Use page placeholders from Application Customizer (Hello World part 2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions)